# getting "memory error" during aws elastic beanstalk docker deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, tensorflow, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a machine learning model with flask api dockerized and when I am trying to deploy it gives me a vague error but checking the expanded logs I can see that it was a memory error when installing tensorflow

As an aside, I also have included the model.h5 file within the docker image, should I not be doing this? Otherwise it is just the .py and config files (no venv in directory)

This is my Dockerfile (it works locally btw, but beanstalk has a memory limit which is getting hit and im not sure why)

```
FROM python:latest

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]

CMD ["app.py", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: What instance are you using? Maybe need to get one with more ram?

Comment: I dont think Im allowed to select an instance on beanstalk? first time using so Im not sure. it's supposed to handle configuring ec2, s3, .. automatically

Comment: Normally you can choose or change instance type. You can do this in Configuraiton of your environment.